# Htaccess won't work with RewriteMap

Tags: htaccess

When the URL link is changed in the administrative panel, and a new map is generated for Apache, I'm encountering an issue with the .htaccess file configuration and RewriteMap. In my Apache configuration, I have a defined RewriteMap function that maps the URL segment 'dystrybucja-i-logistyka' to the variable 'logistyka,' with a constant value of '1'. My goal is to dynamically replace 'dystrybucja-i-logistyka' in the URL with the variable obtained from the RewriteMap.

Here is my relevant .htaccess configuration:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(\w+)
RewriteRule .* - [E=LOGISTICS:${logistics:%1}]

RewriteCond %{ENV:LOGISTICS} !^$
RewriteRule ^%{ENV:LOGISTICS}/(\w+)?$ supply-chain-logistics.php [NC,L]

RewriteMap logistics "txt:C:\wamp\www\photo_gallery\public\maps\map_logistics.txt"
map_logistics.txt logistyka 1
```

That work's

```
RewriteRule ^dystrybucja-i-logistyka/(/\w+)?$ supply-chain-logistics.php [NC,L]
```

With this setup, I expect 'dystrybucja-i-logistyka' in the URL to be replaced by 'logistyka' based on the variable value from the RewriteMap, and the request should be directed to 'supply-chain-logistics.php'.

However, when the URL link is changed in the administrative panel, and a new map is generated for Apache, the change doesn't work as expected. I've confirmed that my RewriteMap function contains the correct mapping.

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Is there something in my configuration that I might have overlooked, or could there be any conflicts?

Comment: Can you please correct the formatting ... it looks like you've defined the RewriteMap in the `.htaccess` file itself; which I'm sure is not the case? Please include the contents of the rewrite map file (is it just `logistyka 1`)?

Comment: "That work's" - You need to explain what you think that is doing. That 2nd rule can't be doing anything. "With this setup, I expect 'dystrybucja-i-logistyka' in the URL to be replaced by 'logistyka' based on the variable value from the RewriteMap" - There doesn't appear to be any relevant "lookup" or "replacement" going on here? If you want to actually "replace" something in the URL then you need to preform an external redirect. (?)

Comment: Please include complete URL examples and an explanation in natural language of what you are trying to achieve. Your part-explanation and code don't appear to match up?

Comment: @MrWhite Thank you for the advice. I've set up RewriteMap in .htaccess for my project. I intend to replace 'dystrybucja-i-logistyka' in the URL with 'logistyka' using RewriteMap. The URLs I want to change are:

    http://localhost/photo_gallery/dystrybucja-i-logistyka/
    http://localhost/photo_gallery/logistyka/

Any help is appreciated

Comment: @MrWhite Because currently, every time someone changes it in the admin panel url to 'logistyka5,' I have to modify it in .htaccess again. In my current setup, I need to change 'RewriteRule ^dystrybucja-i-logistyka/(/\w+)?$ supply-chain-logistics.php [NC,L]' every time from 'dystrybucja-i-logistyka' to 'logistyka'.

Comment: @MrWhite That's why I came up with the idea of using maps, such as map_logistics.txt - logistyka 1. In a month, someone might change the URL to 'quake 1' or 'sagittarius 1'.